# QApplication::processEvents never returns

Tags: event-handling, qt4

In my application I need to wait until external program (using `QProcess`) is finished. I want to keep the application responsible so blocking methods are unacceptable.

Also I need to disallow user input. I've tried to make `QEventLoop` and exec it with `QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents` flag, but as documentation says it only delays an event handling:

> the events are not discarded; they will be delivered the next time `processEvents()` is called without the `ExcludeUserInputEvents` flag.

So I implemented simple event filter and install it on `qApp` (the idea is took from [Qt Application: Simulating modal behaviour (enable/disable user input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009584/qt-application-simulating-modal-behaviour-enable-disable-user-input)). It works well, but sometimes `QApplication::processEvents` function never returns even if I specify the maximum timeout. Could anyone help me to understand **for what reasons it periodically happens**?

```
class UserInputEater : public QObject
{
public:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
    {
        switch(event->type())
        {
        case QEvent::UpdateRequest:
        case QEvent::UpdateLater:
        case QEvent::Paint:
            return QObject::eventFilter(object, event);
        default:
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

-

```
UserInputEater eventEater;
qApp->installEventFilter(&eventEater);

QProcess prc;
prc.start("...");
while(!prc.waitForFinished(10))
{
    if(qApp->hasPendingEvents())
    {
        // Sometimes it never returns from processEvents
        qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100); 
    }
}

qApp->removeEventFilter(&eventEater);
```

**UPD:** Seems like it depends of the timeout value for `QProcess::waitForFinished`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are filtering some useful events (for example, `QEvent::SockAct` could be involved). Try to add some debug output and find out which event types you're actually filtering. Or it might be better to specify the black list of events you want to block instead of white list of events you want to allow. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017400/344347).

Also you shouldn't use `return QObject::eventFilter(object, event);`. You should use `return false`. All other event filters will be called automatically.

This solution however seems weird and unreasonable to me because you can just call `setEnabled(false)` for your top level widget to block user input, and then you can use `QApplication::processEvents` without any flags.

Comment: I posted the same link as you :)

Comment: I know. But you implement this as a white list, and in the linked answer there is a black list. And mentioned event types are different.

Comment: I can't just disable top level widgets because it's not about widgets only, the application globally catches keyboard input. Also I've tried before the black list implementation and I don't know how but mouse click events is still processed. In any cases it's temporary solution and now I just want to understand why `processEvents` doesn't return only sometimes rather than always.